# Select N rows avoiding duplicates on a non-key, non-index field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, how can I select n rows of a non-key, non-index column and avoid duplicate results?

Example table:

```
ID_ | state    | customer | memo
------------------------------------------
1   |  abc     | 123      | memo text xyz
2   |  abc     | 123      | memo text abc
3   |  abc     | 456      | memo text def
4   |  abc     | 456      | memo text rew
5   |  abc     | 789      | memo text yte
6   |  def     | 123      | memo text hrd
7   |  def     | 432      | memo text dfg
```

I want to select, say, 2 memos for state 'abc' but the returned memos should not be for the same customer.

```
memo
----
memo text xyz
memo text def
```

PS: The only select condition available is state (eg: where state = 'abc')

I have managed to do this in a very inefficient way

```
SELECT top 2 MAX(memo)
FROM table
WHERE state = 'abc'
GROUP BY customer
```

This works fine for small sample size, but the production table has over 1 billion rows.

Comment: i hv doubt...do u want the result for customer 789 or not...

Comment: In the example I mentioned, the answer is no, since N in this case is 2. If it was 3, then yes the result would include that of 789.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the following query, in your actual database size. Not sure of the performance in database table with billion rows. So you can do the test yourself.

```
SELECT memo
FROM   (SELECT memo,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
        FROM   table1 WHERE state = 'abc') T
WHERE  RN = 1
```

You can check the ***[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13a3b/4)***

EDIT: Adding a non-clustered index on state and customer including memo will tremendously improve the performance.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [custom_index] ON table 
(
    [state] ASC,
    [customer] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [memo]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [DATA]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify your query as below and add a non-clustered index on state and customer.

SELECT top 2 memo
FROM   (SELECT customer,
               state,
               memo,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
        FROM   table1 WHERE state = 'abc') T
WHERE  RN = 1

Comment: Will wait for alternate suggestions before marking this as the answer.

Comment: Yes definitely, I too wish to know if there is a better solution :) @Jayachandran .Also you can eliminate customer and state from the subquery's select statement.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that :-)

Comment: PS: Will up vote the answer as soon as I have the required reputation.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get that n distinct value for state/customer is to get an ID for every group

```
SELECT MIN(ID_) ID
FROM   Table1
GROUP BY State, customer
```

(`MIN` can be substituted by `MAX`, it's just a way to get one of the values)
then `JOIN` that to the table adding the other condition

```
WITH getID AS (
  SELECT MIN(ID_) ID
  FROM   Table1
  GROUP BY State, customer
)
SELECT TOP 2
       t.ID_, t.State, t.Customer, t.memo
FROM   table1 t
       INNER JOIN getID g ON t.ID_ = g.ID
WHERE  t.state = 'abc'
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c4be/6)</kbd>

if your version of SQLServer doesn't support `WITH` the `CTE` can become a subquery

```
SELECT TOP 2
       t.ID_, t.State, t.Customer, t.memo
FROM   table1 t
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID_) ID
                   FROM   Table1
                   GROUP BY State, customer
                  ) g ON t.ID_ = g.ID
WHERE  t.state = 'abc'
```

---

Another way is to use `CROSS APPLY` to get the distinct `ID`

```
SELECT TOP 2
       t.ID_, t.State, t.Customer, t.memo
FROM   table1 t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                           ID_
                    FROM   table1 t1
                    WHERE  t1.State = t.State AND t1.Customer = t.Customer) c
WHERE  t.state = 'abc'
  AND  c.ID_ = t.ID_;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c4be/11)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Happy to report that this method works as well and gives the expected result. However, when I ran both @TechGirl's and your suggestion (both CTE and subquery) side by side the relative cost split was 40:60. So I am inclined to use to Row Number method.

Comment: :-). I did not mean it as an offence. I was just reporting back my result for others who might find this useful and won't have to re-invent the wheel. As mentioned in the question, my biggest concern is performance. Like I said, your solution works perfectly well.

Comment: Relative cost is something which I checked on the fly. I am still exploring options. One thing I noticed was that your query had a join on an index seek (memo) and an index scan (for id, state and customer) result, where as @TechGirl's had an index seek (for customer and memo) and a filter. Maybe there is a way I can avoid the index scan by using a covering index. But then it is space consuming :(.

Comment: Works, but worsens the performance. The index scan is avoided and is replaced with an index seek, however it is fetching 2 million records compared to a mere 25 of the index scan :-).

Comment: PS: Will up vote the answer as soon as I have the required reputation.